# Sequelize belongsToMany self reference not creating foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a self-referencing belongsToMany relationship with sequelize with a model as the through argument.

However when it creates the table it only creates a foreign key for one of the relationships.

Model:

```
const client = sequelize.define('client', {
    ClientId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4()
    },
    AccessMode: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM('allow_all', 'deny_all', 'selective'),
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            // Tons of other relationships here

            client.belongsToMany(models.client, {
                through: models.clientAccess,
                as: 'clientsWithAccess',
                foreignKey: 'ClientId'
            });

            client.belongsToMany(models.client, {
                through: models.clientAccess,
                as: 'accessToClients',
                foreignKey: 'AccessingClientId'
            });

        }
    }

});
```

The through model:

```
const clientAccess = sequelize.define('clientAccess', {
    Access: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM('allow', 'deny'),
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
```

The resulting table only has the column AccessMode and AccessingClientId. And for some reason AccessingClientId is set as the primary key.

If I switch the placements of the belongsToMany() statements then the name of the field in the table is also reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using the otherKey property of the belongsToMany() method.

```
        client.belongsToMany(models.client, {
            through: models.clientAccess,
            as: 'clientsWithAccess',
            foreignKey: 'ClientId',
            otherKey: 'AccessingClientId'
        });

        client.belongsToMany(models.client, {
            through: models.clientAccess,
            as: 'accessToClients',
            foreignKey: 'AccessingClientId',
            otherKey: 'ClientId'
        });
```

With this the table was created correctly in the database.